# C# DLL does not expose methods

Tags: c#, class, dll

I am working with a C# project that I did not create. I stripped it down very much.

I thought I did everything correctly. It compiles fine, and I can reference the DLL in e. g. a VB.NET application and use it.

However, the DLL's methods are not exposed.

Can somebody tell me if he seems something wrong immediately?

This is the important part of the DLL, I think:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using SevenZip.Compression.LZMA;

namespace SevenZipControl
{
    public static class Zipper
    {
        public static bool compressBytes(byte[] InputBytes,out byte[] OutputBytes)
        {
            OutputBytes=SevenZipHelper.Compress(InputBytes);
            return true;
        }
        public static bool decompressBytes(byte[] InputBytes, out byte[] OutputBytes)
        {
            OutputBytes = SevenZipHelper.Decompress(InputBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I would use it in VB.NET:

```
    Dim c As SevenZipControl.Zipper
    c. (...)
```

But my functions "compressBytes" and "decompressBytes" are not available as one can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks fine, does the referencing assembly have all required subreferences (like SevenZip.Compression)? Try calling the function and building, the error list will tell you if you are missing one.

Comment: " the DLL's methods are not exposed" - what do you mean?

Comment: Your answer would probably involve a lot of guess work because you haven't included any information about how you've attempted to use this, or if this is your code, then nothing about the dll?

Comment: Use this help: http://www.nullskull.com/a/768/7zip-lzma-inmemory-compression-with-c.aspx

Comment: @LordTakkera You mean that I need to reference SevenZip.Compression in the calling application?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov c.ToString() 'ToString is the only method that my DLL exposes :-( I would expect "c.compressBytes(...)" to be available, but it is not in the calling application.

Comment: I have updated my post and added a screenshot. I guess that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To piggyback on @JAnderson's answer, you shouldn't need to instantiate with `Dim`. The following should work:

```
SevenZipControl.Zipper.compressBytes(data)
```

For some info on how the notion of static classes translates into VB, see [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa2427e3-a57f-4c38-adb9-0496d7e3eb9a/static-class-equivalent-in-vbnet?forum=vblanguage)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could make it so that I can call SevenZipControl.compressBytes(data) instead of having to call SevenZipControl.Zipper.compressBytes(data)?

Comment: I don't know how you'd take the class name out. But you should be able to add a using statement like `using SevenZipControl`, and then you would call `Zipper.compressBytes(data)`. In theory, you could try `using SevenZipControl.Zipper As ZipControl` and then use the alias, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Just for clarity, then you would call `ZipControl.compressBytes(data)`

Answer (score 4):

Your code lists static methods. You are creating an instance of the `SevenZipControl.Zipper` class.